# Accept offer coming from WebRTC signalling (in Python)

Tags: python, opencv, webrtc

I am trying to setup a peer-to-server connection in Python, allowing me to parse the video stream in chunks of frames and process them.

On the client side I follow the work of [Insanely Simple WebRTC Video Chat Using Firebase (With Codepen Demo)](https://websitebeaver.com/insanely-simple-webrtc-video-chat-using-firebase-with-codepen-demo).

They use Firebase as a signalling server, and upon connection to the camera, one can call the peer by sending a message that looks as follows:

```
"{\"sdp\":{\"type\":\"offer\",\"sdp\":\"v=0\\r\\no=- 371050945269... (long crypted message)"
```

I am now wondering how I can use this information to accept this offer and capture the video frames coming from this video stream in Python?

I tried the following but this returned that the stream was empty:

```
import cv2

rtsp_url = 'crypto message above'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture({'\"sdp\":{\"type\":\"offer\",\"sdp\" ...')

while True:

    # reads frames (this returned empty)
    ret, img = cap.read()
```

---

Update 08/02: I have looked into [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/tree/master/examples/server) but I have been unable to identify how it relates to the message sent above. In addition, I am unable to install and debug the code on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

That wouldn't work, opencv doesn't know anything about webrtc. You can either grab the frames in the browser using javascript and then send to the python script say over websocket, or use a webrtc library in python like gstreamer. See [this python example](https://gist.github.com/tobiasfriden/3359c9a125c726d9c134359507d3450a) using gstreamer.

Comment: Can you elaborate more which parts of webrtc-sendrecv.py capture the frames in the link you provided? Also, how does it relate to the crypted message above, where does it need to capture it?